# stuck in a promise and returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi im trying so set **String** to data i have fetched. The problem is it is stuck in a promise and returns null before the state can be updated. I am lost as to how I can make sure the data is there before it accesses the data. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from '../components/header.js'
import{BsArrowLeft} from 'react-icons/bs'

const Country = () => {
    const {countryName} = useParams();
    const [country,setCountry] = useState(countryName);
    const [details,setDetails] = useState(null);
    const [string,setString] = useState(null);


    

    useEffect( () => {
        async function fetchData(){
        const res = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`)
        const data = await res.json()
        setDetails(data)  
        setString(Object.keys(data.currencies).toString())
    }
        fetchData() 
    }, [country])
    
        

    
    return (
        <main className='h-screen flex flex-col items-center w-full overflow-x-hidden bg-verylightgrey dark:bg-verydarkblue overflow-scroll'>
            <div className='flex flex-col items-center w-full'>
                <Header/>
                <section className='flex justify-items-start w-full'>
                    <button className='border-2 ml-7 mt-10 mb-16 rounded shadow-md hover:shadow-inner cursor-pointer w-3/12 flex flex-row items-center justify-center text-sm font-light'><span className='mr-2 text-lg'><BsArrowLeft/></span>Back</button>
                </section>
                {details && details.map((data,index) => 
                <div className='w-full flex flex-col items-center' key={index}>
                    <img className='rounded mb-11 w-10/12 h-6/6' alt={data.name.common} src={data.flags.png}/>
                    <section className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                        <h1 className='font-extrabold text-xl ml-7'>{data.name.common}</h1>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-4 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Official Name: </span>{data.name.official}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Population: </span>{data.population}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Region: </span>{data.region}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Sub Region: </span>{data.subregion}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Capital: </span>{data.capital}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-8 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Top Level Domain: </span>{data.tld}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Currencies: </span>{data.currencies[string].name}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Languages: </span></p>
                        <h2 className='font-semibold text-base ml-7 mt-8'>Border Countries:</h2>
                        <button className='border-2 shadow-md rounded cursor-pointer w-24 h-6 ml-7 mt-4 text-xs font-light'>{data.borders}</button>

                    </section>
                </div>)}
            </div>
        </main>
        
    );
}

export default Country;
```

Comment: Your code assigns `data` to `details` and treat `details` as an array with `details.map(...)`. But you also treat it as an object with `data.currencies`. So, is `data` it an array or an object ?

Comment: its an array of an object and the currencies part is :                                
"currencies":{
            "GBP": {
                "name": "British pound",
                "symbol": "£"
            }
        },                        and i need to access GBP in order to get to name. But each country has different currency like EURO or DOLLAR hence why i need to have that part as a string so i can access it like so .....   {data.currencies[string].name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the currency key string accessing code in useEffect(). Based on the data returned from the API, the currencies information can be accessed with below code. This works good when only single currency is returned for a country.

```js
    // setString(Object.keys(data.currencies).toString());
    setString(Object.keys(data[0] && data[0].currencies || {}).toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Your two set states run independently so you have no guarantee about which finished first, adding in a check for both will make sure you have no nulls.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from '../components/header.js'
import{BsArrowLeft} from 'react-icons/bs'

const Country = () => {
    const {countryName} = useParams();
    const [country,setCountry] = useState(countryName);
    const [details,setDetails] = useState(null);
    const [string,setString] = useState(null);


    

    useEffect( () => {
        async function fetchData(){
        const res = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`)
        const data = await res.json()
        setDetails(data)  
        setString(Object.keys(data.currencies).toString())
    }
        fetchData() 
    }, [country])
    
            

    return (
        <main className='h-screen flex flex-col items-center w-full overflow-x-hidden bg-verylightgrey dark:bg-verydarkblue overflow-scroll'>
            <div className='flex flex-col items-center w-full'>
                <Header/>
                <section className='flex justify-items-start w-full'>
                    <button className='border-2 ml-7 mt-10 mb-16 rounded shadow-md hover:shadow-inner cursor-pointer w-3/12 flex flex-row items-center justify-center text-sm font-light'><span className='mr-2 text-lg'><BsArrowLeft/></span>Back</button>
                </section>
                {details && string && details.map((data,index) => 
                <div className='w-full flex flex-col items-center' key={index}>
                    <img className='rounded mb-11 w-10/12 h-6/6' alt={data.name.common} src={data.flags.png}/>
                    <section className='flex flex-col w-full '>
                        <h1 className='font-extrabold text-xl ml-7'>{data.name.common}</h1>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-4 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Official Name: </span>{data.name.official}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Population: </span>{data.population}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Region: </span>{data.region}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Sub Region: </span>{data.subregion}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Capital: </span>{data.capital}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-8 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Top Level Domain: </span>{data.tld}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Currencies: </span>{data.currencies[string].name}</p>
                        <p className='ml-7 mt-2 text-sm font-light'><span className='text-sm font-semibold'>Languages: </span></p>
                        <h2 className='font-semibold text-base ml-7 mt-8'>Border Countries:</h2>
                        <button className='border-2 shadow-md rounded cursor-pointer w-24 h-6 ml-7 mt-4 text-xs font-light'>{data.borders}</button>

                    </section>
                </div>)}
            </div>
        </main>
        
    );
}
```

Comment: **Note**, they run independently because they are inside an async function. In other cases they would be batched and you have access to both variables at the same time.

Comment: i tried this already before but it did not work i end up with this error still : country.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)